# Uploaded Images is being deleted when meteor js restarts

Tags: meteor, collectionfs

I'm still new to Meteor. I'm creating a Meteor JS project and one of the central features of it is image upload or more like a featured image upload. The upload works fine and after clicking on submit it will show on my `<div class="viewing">`. The problem occurs when you restart Meteor. The image will be deleted and thus no image is displayed by the time I run the program.

Here's my code:

The HTML:

```
<body>
    {{> viewPost}}
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> addPost}}
</body>

<template name="addPost">
  <form class="main-form">
    <input type="text" name="title"/>
    <br><br>
    <input type="file" name="imgUp" class="fileIn"/>
    <br><br>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>

<template name="viewPost">
    {{#each images}}
    <div class="viewing">
        <img src="{{this.url store='images'}}"/>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

JS:

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images",{path: "~/uploads"})],
  filter: {
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*'] //allow only images in this FS.Collection
        }
    }
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.addPost.events({
    'submit .main-form': function(event, template){
      var title = event.target.title.value;
      event.preventDefault();
      var fileObj = template.find('input:file');
      Images.insert(fileObj.files[0], function (err,fileObj){});

    }

  });

  Template.viewPost.helpers({
    images: function(){
      return Images.find({});
    }
  });

}
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be great! I've been looking for a way to solve this for a few days already.

Comment: Shouldn't happen. If you create an application that has pretty much only the code you posted here, do you still get the same results?

Comment: do you actually subscribe to that collection, too? Otherwise I could imagine that you are just adding locally on the client, but never really upload it to the server -- nor receive it back next time you log in.

Comment: @MasterAM Yes, I still do get the same results. The code above is what I am currently using.

Comment: @ChristianFritz I see! That figures! I don't subscribe, it's just on my client. I'll try using the Publish and Subscribe and see what happens. Thanks !